# Can we add multiple elements or classes in general siblings Combinators?

Tags: css, web, react-fullstack

Can we add multiple elements or classes in general siblings Combinators?

For Example :

```
.general-class h3 ~ p {
    color: purple;
}
```

And also can we combine two Combinators types in one?

for example

**Descendant Combinators**  +  **General Combinators**  or any two other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In general though you either select **specific** elements or **all** (with `*`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but when you want to target multiple classes or elements you can use the `:is()` selector. A small example:

```
.general-class :is(h1, h2, h3) ~ :is(p, span, div) {
  color: red;
}
```